# How to extract value with simplejson?

Tags: python, simplejson

I have the following json string:

```
{"response":[[{"uid":123456,"name":"LA_"}],[{"cid":"1","name":"Something"}],[{"cid":1,"name":"Something-else"}]]}
```

How can I get `Something` value?
I do the following

```
jstr = json.loads(my_string)
if jstr.get('response'):
    jstr_response = jstr.get('response')[1].get('name')
```

but it doesn't work (`'list' object has no attribute 'get'`)

Comment: It's a dictionary mapped to lists of lists of dictionaries: `(jstr.get('response')[1])[0].get('name')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
jstr = json.loads(my_string)
if jstr.get('response'):
    jstr_response = jstr.get('response')[1][0].get('name')
```